# Getting " Specified URL cannot be found" error while clearing cache

Tags: maintenance-mode

I am working on Maintenance mode screen. I have added outage message in the field, ticked "Put site into maintenance mode" button and save the configuration. Once i clear the cache i am getting "Specified URL cannot be found" error. Please refer to screenshot

[image]

I have checked the logs but can not find anything. I have also tried to Drush cache-rebuild command from console. But still getting same error.

Drupal Version : 8.7

Is anyone aware of this error ?

Comment: Check the logs at `/admin/reports/dblog`.  But most importantly, Drupal 8 is no longer supported and has unfixed security issues.  You need to upgrade: https://www.drupal.org/psa-2021-11-30

Comment: Even the newest version of Drupal 8.7, 8.7.14, is over two years old.

Comment: Hello @PatrickKenny , under security logs i can see this error "Security warning: Couldn't write .htaccess file. Please create a .htaccess file in your private:// directory which contains the following lines:"

But when i checked, .htaccess file is present in present in private folder. 

I am also working to upgrade to version 9. But wanted to know why that error is coming

Comment: Confirm that the private directory path is set correctly in the admin UI.  But, if you are an nginx server, the error is irrelevant because nginx doesn't use `.htaccess`... pretty sure this is fixed in Drupal 9.

Comment: Hello @PatrickKenny private directory is set to sites/default/private_files in file-system